# C#-UWP: How to find if a subfolder exists in a StorageFolder?

Tags: c#, uwp

**Question**: Without using a `foreach` loop how we can find out if a [StorageFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder) has any `SubFolder`. Probably a `C#` guru can help here.

**Why asked**: I am using [StorageFolder.GetFoldersAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfoldersasync) method that returns `IAsyncOperation<IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder>>` and does seem to have [IReadOnlyCollection.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlycollection-1.count?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_IReadOnlyCollection_1_Count) property but I could figure out how to use this property in my following line of code. I do need that count and do not want to use `foreeach` loop to get that count - unless there is not better work around:

```
......
IAsyncOperation<IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder>> MyList = MyStorageFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
......
```

So, how do I apply `count` property to `MyList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I apply count property to MyList

So, you did not know how to call an asynchronous method. Please see [The Task asynchronous programming model in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) and [Asynchronous programming in the UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-universal-windows-platform-apps#asynchronous-programming-in-the-uwp) for details.

For your question, you just need to change your code like the following:

```
private async void YourMethod()
{
    ......
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> MyList = await MyStorageFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
    if (MyList.Count > 0)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("SubFolder exists.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the link and nicely formatting/explaining your solution.